How to read BigQuery auth view using python pipeline code in GCP Dataflow
We are trying to extract the data from BigQuery authorized view(GCP PROJECT2) which is created pointing to the source view (which is available in GCP PROJECT 1) using Dataflow + apache beam python and getting the below error :

"Ërror Result: <ErrorProto message: 'Not found: Dataset 'xxxx.xxxx.xxx' was not found in the location US' reason: notFound">"

Appreciate your help.

which dataset is not found? _S or _T (see my answer/suggestion)?

HI, Did you plz check the location for the Dataset is same for the both projects . If the location is not same in both projects dataset then generally we get that error . Let me know if this helps or not .

In principle this should be doable, the fact that it doesn't suggest you still have a IAM issue.
Suppose the GCP project in which Dataflow runs is project_T containing the dataset_T with the BigQuery view view_T pointing to the GCP project project_S with dataset_Sand view_S (suffix _T for target and suffix _S for source).
Can you verify the following:

The Dataflow service account executing the code (project_T) on the workers has roles/bigquery.dataViewer on dataset_T
view_T is set as an authorized view in dataset_S (has to be set within project_S)
view_T only queries views/tables from dataset_S and nothing else from project_S. If more datasets are involved, it is authorized for the additional datasets in project_S as well
Dataflow does not (accidently) query anything directly from project_S, but only view_T

